# How is it possible to have a function of a variable in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump, julia-studio

if you don't mind, would you please help me that how can I have a function of x as follow:

this function calculate two values for x

```
function MOP2(x)
    n=length(x);
    z1=1-exp(sum((x-1/sqrt(n)).^2));
    z2=1-exp(sum((x+1/sqrt(n)).^2));
    z=[z1;z2];
    return z
end
```

in main code I want to have

```
costfunc=F(x)
```

but I don't know it exists in Julia or not. in matlab we can have that as following

```
costfunc=@(x)  MOP2(x)
```

is there any function like `@` in Julia?

Thanks very much.

Comment: In Matlab you would just write `costfunc = @MOP2`, without the `x`. And similarly for Julia, just write `costfunc = MOP2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a syntax for that.

These are called anonymous functions (although you can assign them a name).

Here are a few ways to do this.

```
x -> x^2 + 3x + 9
x -> MOP2(x) # this actually is redundant. Please see the note below

# you can assign anonymous functions a name
costFunc = x -> MOP2(x)


# for multiple arguments
(x, y) -> MOP2(x) + y^2

# for no argument
() -> 99.9

# another syntax
function (x)
    MOP2(x)
end
```

Here are a few usage examples.

```
julia> map(x -> x^2 + 3x + 1, [1, 4, 7, 4])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 29
 71
 29


julia> map(function (x) x^2 + 3x + 1 end, [1, 4, 7, 4]) 
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 29
 71
 29
```

---

Note that you do not need to create an anonymous function like `x -> MOP2(x)`. If a function takes another function, you can simply pass `MOP2` instead of passing `x -> MOP2(x)`. Here is an example with `round`.

```
julia> A = rand(5, 5);
julia> map(x -> round(x), A)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> map(round, rand(5, 5))
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

There is also [the `do` syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/index.html#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments-1) while passing functions as arguments.

If you want to give a name to your anonymous function, you might as well define another function like

```
costFunc(x) = MOP2(x) + sum(x.^2) + 4
```

and use `costFunc` later.

If you want to call a function with another name you may write

```
costFunc = MOP2
```

if it is inside a function. Otherwise. in global scope, it is better to add `const` before the assignment statement.

```
const constFunc = MOP2
```

This is important for type-stability reasons.